# Quadratic variation - Semimartingale

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis, quadratic-variation

We know that any Semimartingale has Quadratic variation. I am interested to know if the converse is also true i.e. if a process has quadratic variation then it is semimartingale. Can some one prove/disprove it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hi if you take any process that is not a semi-martingale with null quadratic variations (for example a fractional Brownian motion with Hurst parameter less than 1/2) and then you add some jumps, then it has non null quadratic variations (the square of its jumps) and you have a counterexample.

Best regards

Comment: fBm with H<1/2 has infinite quadratic variation