# Why Are Semimartingales the Largest Possible Class of Stochastic Integrators?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

I am trying to understand why semimartingales are the most general possible class of stochastic integrators. (I was hoping that [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1170508/quadratic-variation-and-semimartingales) would give me my answer, but it didn't.)

I thought at first it was because they were the most general class of processes with defined quadratic variation.

(Because I thought local martingales are supposed to be the most general class for which the quadratic variation was non-zero and could not be decomposed into the sum of non-trivial processes, one with zero quadratic variation, and because adapted processes of locally bounded variation have zero quadratic variation.)

However, it turns out that this is ***not*** the content of the Bichteler-Dellacherie theorem (as I had expected). Furthermore, there are apparently counter-examples involving fractional Brownian motion (which I do not understand at all) [Quadratic variation - Semimartingale](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/698446/quadratic-variation-semimartingale)

The definition of the stochastic integral, when moving from Brownian motion for which the differential is just $dt$ because the quadratic variation is $t$, to arbitrary local martingales, and then semimartingales, clearly has something to do with quadratic variation, but I feel like I must be missing some part of the story if semimartingales are not the most general processes for which quadratic variation exists, is defined, and can be non-zero.

**EDIT:** I guess it probably has something to do with p.52 of Protter, *Stochastic Integration and Differential Equations*, namely where a semimartingale $X_t$ is defined as any adapted process such that it is cadlag and for which the integral of the simple predictable process $H_t$ $$I_X(H)= H_0X_0 + \Sigma_{i=1}^n H_i [X_{T_{i+1}}-X_{T_i}]$$ is continuous.

However, what I don't understand:

**1.** Why cadlag?

I assume because it guarantees only jump discontinuities, and with that at most countably many discontinuities (like for a distribution function? or is that only because a distribution function is increasing -- if we don't have that the sample paths are of locally bounded variation anymore, does it still hold that we can only have countably many jump discontinuities?)

**2.** Why do we care if that integral is continuous?

I know it forms the basis for the Ito integral, but what's wrong with having it be a discontinuous process? (If for example we can generalize from continuous semimartingales to arbitrary semimartingales which must be cadlag, why can't we consider cadlag integrals?)

Comment: What's continuous here is the map $H\mapsto I_X(H)$ (in a certain sense, detailed by Protter), which is an entirely natural thing to ask of an integral.

Comment: Oh so it's not a requirement on the indefinite integral itself. Why is it "natural" to ask of an integral? I get why it would be convenient, but not much else.

Comment: We need some kind of "stability" in $I_X$, otherwise, if your $H$ change a tiny little bit, your $I_X(H)$ is light years away, such mapping will not be useful.  In Protter's, $H$ is measured using the "strongest" topology (uniform convergence), and $J_X(H)$ using the "weakest" topology (convergence in probability), and such $J_X$ will be the "most" general.

Comment: That makes a lot more sense to me now; thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out George Lowther's blog:
https://almostsure.wordpress.com/2010/01/03/the-stochastic-integral/
Especially Lemma 3, answers your question "why cadlag?"

Comment: I have seen his blog before, but did not know about this post -- you are right, this is very helpful, especially Lemma 3! Thank you so much!